# Проблемы с Rabbitmq

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Использую php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle
Все работает нормально до момента пока Rabbit не обваливается.
Вопрос: как можно избежать этих ошибок

> [ErrorException]
>   fwrite(): send of 8 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe
>
> Exception trace:  () at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:285
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->error_handler() at n/a:n/a 
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:374
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write_heartbeat() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:359
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->check_heartbeat() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:410
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->select() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:231
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php:149
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php:106
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:513
>   PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:560
>   PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php:217
>   PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->next_frame() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php:327
>   PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->wait() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle/RabbitMq/Consumer.php:88
>   OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Consumer->consume() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle/Command/BaseConsumerCommand.php:90
>   OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\Command\BaseConsumerCommand->execute() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:240
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:876
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:215
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:71
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:122
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/bin/console:27
>
> ---
>
> ```
>                                               [PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]     Invalid frame type 65
> ```
>
> Exception trace:  () at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:519
>   PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:560
>   PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php:217
>   PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->next_frame() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php:327
>   PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->wait() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle/RabbitMq/Consumer.php:88
>   OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Consumer->consume() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle/Command/BaseConsumerCommand.php:90
>   OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\Command\BaseConsumerCommand->execute() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:240
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:876
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:215
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:71
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:122
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/bin/console:27
>
> ---
>
> [PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]     Broken pipe or
>   closed connection
>
> Exception trace:  () at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:211
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->read() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php:149
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->rawread() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/AMQPReader.php:106
>   PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPReader->read() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:513
>   PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_frame() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:560
>   PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->wait_channel() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php:217
>   PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->next_frame() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php:327
>   PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->wait() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle/RabbitMq/Consumer.php:88
>   OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Consumer->consume() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle/Command/BaseConsumerCommand.php:90
>   OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\Command\BaseConsumerCommand->execute() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:240
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:876
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:215
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:71
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:122
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
>   /home/hoster/sms.adm.tools/deploy-20180601112736-d7871684132ddb1dd6bd76693341e62dd9407e93/bin/console:27

Или в консьюмере проверять что ребит лежит и ждать пока он не перезапустится. Код консьюмера

```
class MessageConsumer implements ConsumerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Sender
     */
    protected $sender;

    /**
     * @return Sender
     */
    public function getSender()
    {
        return $this->sender;
    }

    /**
     * @param Sender $sender
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSender(Sender $sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param AMQPMessage $msg
     * @return void
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     */
    public function execute(AMQPMessage $msg)
    {
        $messageId = $msg->getBody();
        $this->getSender()->process($messageId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Так может стоит проверить почему он падает? Он ведь просто так падать не будет. То что вы здесь описали это следствие обрыва связи с ним. А информацию по этой ошибке можно найти на официальном репозитории этой библиотеки (https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/issues/424)

Comment: Вы верно говорите, почему он падает я разбираюсь. Но мне бы все же хотелось, что бы если даже он упал, то консьюмер продолжал работать, тоесть что бы он видел, ага реббит лежит и дальше не чего не делать и слушать дальше, как только супервизор перезапустил реббит, то консьмер продолжал работать дальше. Тоесть мне нужна какая-то проверка, если ребит работает - ок, если нет, то что бы не вываливал ошибки подключения. как я понимаю это нужно делать какой-то кастомный консольный скрипт который будет это все проверять, так как в готовой либе я такого функционала не нашел

Comment: Да, для этого придется встраивать heartbeat (сердебиение) для проверки на работоспособность.